# Separability of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I was reading this paper [Separability - Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf).

So if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{K}$ there is a $f_1(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ such that $f_1(\alpha)=0$. If $f_1(x)$ is a irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{K}[x]$ then OK. If not $\exists f_2(x), g(x)\in \mathbb{K}[x]$ such that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)g(x)$, $f_2(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha)\neq0$. I can repeat the process until I have $f(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ minimal
and irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$. Once $f(x)$ is irreducible each of its root has multiplicity $1$, therefore $\alpha$ is separable over $\mathbb{K}$.

Is this right? Thus we have that any algebraic element of $\mathbb{K}$ is separable?

---

Krish,

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ nonzero irreducible polynomial and $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. In some splitting field over $\mathbb{K}$ we have $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^{m}h(x)$, $h(\alpha)\neq0$. Suppose $m>1$ then:
$$f'(x)=m(x-\alpha)^{m-1}h(x)+(x-\alpha)^mh'(x)\Rightarrow f'(\alpha)=0.$$
Since $f'(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ and $deg(f(x))>deg(f'(x))$ we arrive at a contradiction, so $m=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take  $K = F_2(t),$ field of rational polynomial in $t$ over $F_2$ and consider the polynomial $x^2 + t \in K[x].$ This is irreducible, but not separable.

Comment: But $x^2+t$ is the irreducible polynomial of what element in $K$?

Comment: $x^2 + t$ is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt t.$ In this case $(- \sqrt t) = \sqrt t.$ So the roots are not different as you claimed in the last line of your argument.

Comment: OK, can you see what I did wrong?

Comment: "Once $f(x)$ is irreducible each of its root has multiplicity 1," this is *not* true (as you see in the above example).

Comment: As I edited, what's wrong?

Comment: Another thing, as $\sqrt t\in K$?

Comment: No. $\sqrt t \notin K.$ If $\sqrt t \in K,$ write $\sqrt t = \frac{p(t)}{q(t)}, p(t), q(t) \in F_2[t], q(t) \neq 0, \text{gcd}(p(t), q(t))=1.$ Then $(q(t))^2\cdot t = (p(t))^2.$ So...?